# RecyclerView doesn't swap adapters, onBindViewHolder IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to utilize my API in my app to update a RecyclerView based on a Google MapView location, so this means the API will return lists of different sizes, and frequently. 
After the initial app loads, when I change locations I trigger a new API call which creates a new Adapter and calls the `RecyclerView.swapAdapter()` method. 
This seems like a super simple solution but I can't find anything in the RecyclerView or RecyclerView.ViewHolder docs to address this.

Here's the issue:

- if the API returns a list larger than the initial list size, the recyclerview stays the same size as the initially loaded list size
- if the API returns a list smaller than the initial list size, there's a runtime error that returns a IndexOutOfBoundsException

Here is the basic code stucture I have:

**Inside my API class**

```
public void getFeed(final RecyclerView recView, final Location loc){

    service().getFeed(MyFeeds.API_FEED).enqueue(new Callback<NearbyPeopleProto.NearbyPeopleFeed>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<NearbyPeopleProto.NearbyPeopleFeed> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "recview Child count: " + recView.getChildCount());
            ArrayList<NearbyPeople> near = new RtGtfsParser(c).getStopsByLocation(response.body(), loc);

            /*Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onResponse: " + recView.getChildCount() + " -- " + near.get(0).getStops().size());
            if(recView.getChildCount() > near.get(0).getStops().size()) {
                //recView.removeViews(near.get(0).getStops().size() - 1, recView.getChildCount() - 1);
                recView.removeViewAt(1);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onResponse: " + recView.getChildCount());
            }*/

            GroupListAdapter ta = new GroupListAdapter(c, near);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onResponse: Swapping");
            //recView.setAdapter(ta);

            recView.swapAdapter(ta, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

**My Adapter class**

```
public class GroupListAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<GroupListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<NearbyPeople> NearbyPeople;

    public GroupListAdapter(ArrayList<NearbyPeople> NearbyPeople) {
        this.NearbyPeople = NearbyPeople;
    }

    @Override
    public GroupListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View stationView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(stationView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GroupListAdapter.ViewHolder vh, int position) {

        if(NearbyPeople.get(0).getStops() != null) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + NearbyPeople.get(0).getStops().size());
            vh.locationTag.setText(NearbyPeople.get(0).getStops().get(position).stopName);
        } else {
            vh.locationTag.setText("Loading...");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return NearbyPeople.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView locationTag;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            locationTag = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_tag);
        }
    }
}
```

**LogCat Output:**

```
01-12 22:36:27.718 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/TripActivity: onCameraChange: 
//API gets called on the initial app load
01-12 22:36:28.597 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp I/System.out: LOADING MAP
01-12 22:36:28.622 6821-6831/net.mastrgamr.myapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.511ms
01-12 22:36:28.633 6821-6831/net.mastrgamr.myapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 16785(866KB) AllocSpace objects, 9(3MB) LOS objects, 0% free, 68MB/68MB, paused 16.852ms total 67.527ms
01-12 22:36:28.635 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/TripActivity: onMyLocationChange: Location[fused 40.882174,-73.833406 acc=50 et=+2d19h35m3s487ms]
01-12 22:36:28.685 6821-6831/net.mastrgamr.myapp I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2960(217KB) AllocSpace objects, 28(26MB) LOS objects, 24% free, 48MB/64MB, paused 5.893ms total 47.174ms
01-12 22:36:28.903 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/ApiService: recview Child count: 1
01-12 22:36:28.906 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/NearbyGroups: mapping to model
01-12 22:36:28.913 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp I/System.out: MAPPED!!: [net.mastrgamr.tpulse.models.realtime.NearbyGroups$Stops@6ebd215, net.mastrgamr.tpulse.models.realtime.NearbyGroups$Stops@da9092a]
01-12 22:36:28.913 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/NearbyGroups: mapping to model
01-12 22:36:28.926 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp I/System.out: MAPPED!!: [net.mastrgamr.tpulse.models.realtime.NearbyGroups$Stops@23fe31b, net.mastrgamr.tpulse.models.realtime.NearbyGroups$Stops@e481cb8]
01-12 22:36:28.927 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/ApiService: onResponse: Swapping
01-12 22:36:28.943 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/GroupListAdpter: onBindViewHolder: 2
01-12 22:36:28.952 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/GroupListAdpter: onBindViewHolder: 2
01-12 22:36:29.996 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/TripActivity: onCameraChange: 
01-12 22:36:33.397 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/TripActivity: onCameraChange: 
//API also gets called when the map is moved.
01-12 22:36:33.399 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/TripActivity: CAMERA MOVED -- Regenerating: Location[Moved Location 40.880845,-73.837932 acc=??? t=?!? et=?!?]
01-12 22:36:33.749 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/ApiService: recview Child count: 2
01-12 22:36:33.749 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/NearbyGroups: mapping to model
01-12 22:36:33.755 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp I/System.out: MAPPED!!: [net.mastrgamr.tpulse.models.realtime.NearbyGroups$Stops@90eab4a]
01-12 22:36:33.755 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/NearbyGroups: mapping to model
01-12 22:36:33.762 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp I/System.out: MAPPED!!: [net.mastrgamr.tpulse.models.realtime.NearbyGroups$Stops@8abaabb]
01-12 22:36:33.763 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/ApiService: onResponse: Swapping
01-12 22:36:33.770 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/GroupListAdpter: onBindViewHolder: 1
01-12 22:36:33.772 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/GroupListAdpter: onBindViewHolder: 1
01-12 22:36:33.778 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-12 22:36:33.995 6821-6821/net.mastrgamr.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: net.mastrgamr.myapp, PID: 6821
                                                                          java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
                                                                              at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                              at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                              at net.mastrgamr.tpulse.adapters.GroupListAdpter.onBindViewHolder(GroupListAdpter.java:63)
                                                                              at net.mastrgamr.tpulse.adapters.GroupListAdpter.onBindViewHolder(GroupListAdpter.java:25)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5217)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5250)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4487)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4363)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
```

Comment: can you edit the question with `logcat` output?

Comment: seems like there is only one item in the ArrayList, index `0`, and you are trying to access values at index value `1`

Comment: @oblivion I understand that part, but that shouldn't be the case if I'm swapping/setting a new adapter (with new contents) altogether

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was an elementary bug. Might have been hard to miss if you are not aware of my adapter's list structure.

**My Adapter code**

```
    -----
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GroupListAdapter.ViewHolder vh, int position) {

        if(NearbyPeople.get(0).getStops() != null) {
            // the line below accesses an inner array to get to the info i really want
            vh.locationTag.setText(NearbyPeople.get(0).getStops().get(position).stopName);
        } else {
            vh.locationTag.setText("Loading...");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return NearbyPeople.size(); //Causing bug/runtime error. This only accesses the root 'node' of the array
    }
   -----
```

The issue was in `getItemCount()`. I use this adapter to display information based on 1 of 2 inner arrays within a 'root' array. I was only returning the size of the root array in `getItemCount()` (which is only 2).

That's why when I was getting API results less than 1 my app would throw a RuntimeException, and if the results returned an array larger than 2, it would still show only 2 elements in my RecyclerView.

Answer (score 2):

`Swap` between two `list` will work only if they are of same size, if one of the `list` is shorter or larger than other your `swap` will not work as expected, you are getting a assumed result.

Example: `String one = {"1","2"}` swap with `String two = {"4","8","10"}`. you know what will happen the last element will be discarded in the `two` array as `one` array does not have the 3rd element.

Although [swapAdapter();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setAdapter%28android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter%29), does not show the documentation this is something you can assume.

The best and fastest way to deal with it is to make a new `adapter` and assign it to the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: So I should call setAdapter? That's where my confusion comes in, because when I do call setAdapter the error still shows.. Which doesn't make sense since the RecyclerView is getting a whole new adapter so how is it still referencing the old data to be throwing this exception?

Comment: you have you instantiate new adapter with the new list you get, after that assign that to the recyclerView

Comment: isn't that what I'm doing in my API class? I create a new ArrayList, and passing that new list into a new GroupListAdapter, and calling recView.setAdapter(); (ignore the swapAdapter line, see the commented line above that)

Comment: @mastrgamr, did you change the code? kindly update that in question let me see if anything is missing

Comment: Haven't changed anything in my project since I posted this question, this is the latest source code available. Would the fact that the recyclerview is final mean that I can't change its adapter?

Comment: if you are in not in hurry give me some time, i will write some code for you if you are willing to share the link for the list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100604/discussion-between-mastrgamr-and-pankaj-nimgade).